# What is the smallest increment of space and the smallest increment of time?

Tags: spacetime, discrete

I believe that every point in space is a surface point. And if it was possible to break through or tear a point in space, it will create a black hole. I believe that's why a black hole can exist anywhere in space. Since every point in space is a surface edge then punching through a point in space will causes matter to get suck into a very powerful and vast vacuum (outside of our universe). Does any of this hold water? And what about the smallest increment of time and space? Where can I find supporting Theory and equations, if any?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. The help center says: "Some kinds of questions should not be asked here: [..] Pitches for your own personal theories or work
We deal with mainstream physics here. Anything that couldn't be published in a reputable journal is not appropriate on this site."

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are talking about. It would help greatly if you defined your terms "surface point" and "surface edge" and what you mean by "break through" or "tear." None of this is standard terminology - it sounds like words you've just made up on the spot that could mean absolutely anything (or nothing). Anyway, the standard theory of black holes doesn't have anything getting "sucked out of our universe."

Comment: [Non-mainstream ideas: Not appropriate.](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site)  Unless you remove all the parts about "I believe".

Answer (score 2):

No. Your notion imposes a fixed space with real points of defined size in a defined space. That is inconsistent with experimental observations of and cannot be made consistent with either relativity or QM. Also, one does not need to suck things out of our universe with some contrived vacuum. There is no outside needed. The black hole arises from gravity and gravity is a force that acts on all forms of energy and matter.